# Удаление из 1 списка другого по не точному вхождению

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имею 2 списка:

```
a_one = ['работа','школьный','учиться','работать','портфель']
b_one = ['раб', 'школ']
```

Мне нужно из списка a удалить список b, как видно список b у нас имеет не точное вхождение фразы, по этой причине я так понимаю, мне нужно использовать регулярные выражения.

Просто перебор таким способом, не работает:

```
for i in a_one:    
    if i in b_one:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Почему не работает? Должно работать

Comment: Потому что список b_one имеет не точное вхождение я так понимаю.

Comment: А, все, понял. Вы ищете `i` в `b_one`, а надо наоборот - проверять что ни один элемент `b_one` не входит в 'i'

Comment: Да, я вот тоже думал двумя циклами, но почему то вариант с регулярками показался лучше, видимо я ошибался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вот так получилось простыми циклами сделать

```
a_one = ['работа', 'школьный', 'учиться', 'работать', 'портфель']
b_one = ['раб', 'школ']
res = set()

for i in a_one:
    for j in b_one:
        if j in i:
            res.add(i)
        else:
            continue

print(list(set(a_one) ^ res))   # ['учиться', 'портфель']
```

Comment: Какой-то бесполезный сет...

Comment: А else ещё более бесполезный...

Answer (score 2):

Если годится сложить в новый список, а не чистить существующий, то можно так:

https://ideone.com/vjZd3X

```
a = ['работа','школьный','учиться','работать','портфель']
b = ['раб', 'школ']

res = [x for x in a if all(y not in x for y in b)]

print(res)
```